# WPF / C# Updating ListBox with ObservableCollection (directory monitoring)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, observablecollection

I just found out that I can't use FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory for changes in contents thanks to Novell, so I have to implement my own version.  One of the problems I'm having, besides the fact that my implementation might be inefficient, is that my ListBox in my UI does not get updated with the list of files.

Here's my Folder class:

```
   public class FolderWatcher
   {
    // This collection will contain the files in the folder
    public static AsyncObservableCollection<FileItem> folder = new AsyncObservableCollection<FileItem>();

    // Timer
    System.Timers.Timer timer;

    // Path
    string path;

    // Extension type
    string extension;

    //The next line is important to allow system for us to monitor it.  It's a trust setting, and we need Full Trust.
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void Run(string dirPath, string extensionFilter)
    {
        // Set path and extension
        path = dirPath;
        extension = extensionFilter;

        // Populate the folder list with the current files
        var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        foreach (var currentFile in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            var aFile = new FileItem
            {
                Name = currentFile.Name,
                Path = currentFile.FullName
            };

            folder.Add(aFile);
        }

        // Start the timer
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;

        // When timer elapses, raise an event
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(UpdateFiles);
    }

    // Update Files
    private void UpdateFiles(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get directory info
        var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        // Create a temporary list to hold new items
        AsyncObservableCollection<FileItem> temp = new AsyncObservableCollection<FileItem>();

        // Add the items into the temporary list
        foreach (var currentFile in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            var aFile = new FileItem
            {
                Name = currentFile.Name,
                Path = currentFile.FullName
            };

            temp.Add(aFile);
        }

        // Check for new files first, checking if they've been renamed as well
        int count = temp.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // If main folder list doesn't contain a new file, add it
            if (!folder.Contains(temp[i]))
            {
                folder.Add(temp[i]);
            }
        }

        // Now check to see if any files have been removed
        count = folder.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // If temp folder doesn't contain these files, remove them
            if (!temp.Contains(folder[i]))
            {
                folder.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FileItem:

```
public class FileItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _Name; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                _Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _Path;

    public string Path 
    { 
        get { return _Path; }
        set
        {
            if (_Path != value)
            {
                _Path = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Path");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
            return _Path;
    }
}
```

Modified ObservableCollection:

```
public class AsyncObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    public AsyncObservableCollection()
    {
    }

    public AsyncObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == _synchronizationContext)
        {
            // Execute the CollectionChanged event on the current thread
            RaiseCollectionChanged(e);
        }
        else
        {
            // Post the CollectionChanged event on the creator thread
            _synchronizationContext.Post(RaiseCollectionChanged, e);
        }
    }

    private void RaiseCollectionChanged(object param)
    {
        // We are in the creator thread, call the base implementation directly
        base.OnCollectionChanged((NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)param);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == _synchronizationContext)
        {
            // Execute the PropertyChanged event on the current thread
            RaisePropertyChanged(e);
        }
        else
        {
            // Post the PropertyChanged event on the creator thread
            _synchronizationContext.Post(RaisePropertyChanged, e);
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(object param)
    {
        // We are in the creator thread, call the base implementation directly
        base.OnPropertyChanged((PropertyChangedEventArgs)param);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Above is an updated code.  I'm just working on getting it to update properly, but everything else seems to work just fine.  I'll update when it's fully functional so that others can use.

I ended up rewriting my old code, it was getting out of hand and hard to manage.  I decided to simplify it, for now it's using strings, but can be just as easily used for my FileItem... here's a snippet (it's not split up into files because this was a test app):

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        // Must be used (read MSDN documentation)
        InitializeComponent();

        // Our main collection to hold names of files
        this.dir = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        // Bind our collection to the listbox as the source of data
        TheListBox.ItemsSource = dir;

        // Target directory path
        dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp");

        // Set timer (2 seconds is optimal for overhead and quick updates... increase or decrease based on system performance)
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;

        // Add an event handler for timer elapsing
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(UpdateFiles);
    }

    // Updates Files in the directory collection
    private void UpdateFiles(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Temporary collection that will help us compare files and avoid errors
        ObservableCollection<string> temp = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        // Since we're using a timer, we have to invoke the changes into the main thread, or we'll get an access exception on dir
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            (Action)delegate()
            {
                // Populate the temporary collection with files
                foreach (var file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.ToString()))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            temp.Add(file.ToString());
                        }
                        catch (Exception listE)
                        {
                            // log exception
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Check to see if there are any new files
                foreach (var item in temp)
                {
                    if (!dir.Contains(item.ToString()) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString()))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            dir.Add(item.ToString());
                        }
                        catch (Exception listE)
                        {
                            // log exception
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Check to see if any files have been moved/renamed
                for (int i = 0; i < dir.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!temp.Contains(dir[i].ToString()) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dir[i].ToString()))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            dir.RemoveAt(i);
                        }
                        catch (Exception listE)
                        {
                            // log exception
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

It works and it works well.  No errors, nothing.  I'm sure there's a way to make it even shorter, but that'll be on you.  I thought I'd share this with anyone running into a similar problem.

Comment: Make filelist a property just in case and implement INotifyPropertyChanged...

Comment: You might want to use a BackgoundWorker for this seeing as how getfiles could get slow on excessively large filesystems, etc.. And you could update with your updated (not working) code ^_^.

Comment: Excellent point about the possibility of large directories, Directory.GetFiles should be replaced with Directory.EnumerateFiles to remove the need to load the complete file list prior to enumerating.

Comment: Directories will be fairly small.  I just can't get this code to update.  See above for my old/new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileWatcher` needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and change `fileList` to a property that raises the event:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<string> _fileList;
    public ObservableCollection<string> fileList
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileList;
        }
        set
        {
            _fileList= value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("fileList"));
        }
    }
```

Raising the event is what notifies the UI that the underlying data has changed and needs to be updated.

Comment: I had to change everything to non-static to be able to implement your code; however, it still doesn't update the list.

Comment: @StefanDenchev Yeah, I had everything working flawless when I had FileSystemWatcher and now it's all broken.

Comment: @StefanDenchev Correct.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` forces the `PropertyChanged` event handler to be non-static...

Comment: @Noobacode This should work... is the property still updating, and the UI is not?

Comment: @Noobacode Make sure you're passing the property name correctly and you are updating the property, not the field... No idea why it wouldn't work... Oh, and sorry for the spam, Jimmie...

Comment: So, I took my old code from when I used FileSystemWatcher and I just changed the Watcher.... it still wouldn't update.  I think it has to do with how I raise an event for timer elapsing.  Something's not right there.